# Conversion From Transverse Mercator To Longitude & Lattitude

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, datum, proj

I have to transform (7-parameters datum transformation) coordinates from northings & eastings to lattitude & longitude.

Following are details of source coordinate system(i.e. northings & eastings one) :

```
1) Projection Details: 
 1.1)Projection Name
 1.2)Origin Lat/Lon
 1.3)Origin North/East
 1.4)Scaling Factor
2)Datum Name: AGD84
3)7-parameter Datum Details:
 3.1)Rotn X:0.292
 3.2)Rotn Y:-0.443
 3.3)Rotn Z:-0.277
 3.4) Trans X:117.763
 3.5) Trans Y:-51.51
 3.6)Trans Z:139.061
 3.7)Scaling Factor:-0.03939657799319541
```

Please note that I am using `"Proj4Js"` for the above mentioned transformation for which following is the "defs" settings:

```
***Proj4js.defs["<EPSG-CODE>"] = "+proj=<someProjectionImplementation>  
+towgs84=-117.763,-51.51,139.061,0.292,-0.443,-0.277,-0.03939657799319541 +no_defs";***
```

Could anyone confirm that is there any issue in this setting?

Thanks,
Gajendra

Comment: towgs84=-117.763 Should be towgs84=117.763

Comment: @HansErren : Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look very carefully at the signs when writing a towgs84 statement, in this case a minus sign was wrongly inserted, towgs84=-117.763 should be towgs84=117.763